How to compile my own Couenne solver using Windows
I am having some difficulty compiling Couenne 0.5.8 as a solver for Pyomo using Windows.
As I am quite new to this (compiling solvers), I would greatly appreciate any help to guide me through how to compile using the latest version of Couenne.
Here is a video I saw but it uses Ubuntu - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0uwyRaXmcw
I am also having difficulty following the instructions from Git - https://github.com/coin-or/Couenne?tab=readme-ov-file

That's no fun (and this is an euphemism)!
There are a few possible routes here, ranked from most recommended to least recommended
1. Reconsider your usage of Windows
Build tooling on Windows is so incredibly bad that you will struggle with lots of (academic) codebases which are highly biased towards Linux/Mac.
Since WSL/WSL2 (basically Linux kernel running on Windows) i don't really see why anyone should bother with Windows anymore. Even GUIs would work on modern versions.
2. Download prebuilt binaries from AMPL
Once upon a time, AMPL provided Windows binaries (e.g. couenne.exe) of all those Open-Source Solvers without any registration process.
But it seems in todays world, businesses just don't work anymore without grabbing user data all the time as https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source-solvers/ also asks for "something" nowadays.
Decide yourself if this is an acceptable route (and figure out yourself what kind of license terms apply). While i have not checked it, i guess this is a painfree route towards some statically compiled couenne.exe which just works (i have used their binaries many years ago without any issues).
3. Compilation from source? -> coinbrew
If both routes above are infeasible, you are in a tough spot. Compilation from sources on Windows is extremely hard! I did so many years ago, with success, but there was lots of pain (and my background is CS... still the build-tooling is from the 90s...).
Whatever you do... use https://github.com/coin-or/coinbrew the reason being, that couenne depends on tons of other projects you also have to build (Clp, Cbc, Cgl, Bonmin, Ipopt, LAPACK, OpenBlas, CoinUtils, METIS, and more...!!!!). coinbrew handles those dependencies.
BUT to use coinbrew you need a (cross-)compilation toolchain.
https://coin-or.github.io/user_introduction.html has some documentation on this and to summarize: yes... i did build those things in the past with the MSYS2/MinGW/gcc way (how their docs call it). It works. But probably not on first try. You also need to understand those toolchains  (e.g. MSYS2) and their package-managers (e.g. pacman) first.
But if you intend to build lots of academic code on Windows, this is a necessary tool anyway (eventually) as native Windows compilation has strong limitations (last time i checked there was no free Fortran compiler on Windows and tons of optimization-related code uses Fortran).
4. Search for other prebuilt binaries and use them
I quickly did that with Julia and installing Couenne_jll (which triggers the downloading of windows-compatible binaries of couenne and it's dependencies; you can also see that they are using a MinGW-based toolchain!) before manually collecting all those exe/dll files in julias folder (those related to couenne but also julia-related ones like libwinpthread-1.dll) for our non julia-related purposes.
While i could start couenne in the terminal eventually, there were issues when i ran some pyomo example.. So not recommended...

thank you very much for these! it is really challenging to this with my current setup. i see that couenne is not really your top choice. will consider using other solvers such as SHOT (which requires compiling too!)

It's not really about Couenne alone, but all CoinOR-related software isn't easy to setup on Windows. SHOT is not much different (shares a lot of deps with Couenne). It's docs and Github repo also show, that they once distributed prebuilt Windows binaries (2020) but stopped doing that although solver-development continues. It's just a hassle.

thank you for this clarification! i have downloaded from AMPL and managed to get some results from couenne. :) thanks again sascha
